# How to change app display name for Signin with Apple

Tags: swift, xcode, sign-in-with-apple

I have implemented Signin with apple in my Xcode project.
After use signin, In the settings its showing diffrent name of application for apple login.

I searched in whole xcode project, but there is not same or similar string. From where I can change the display name and Icon of app which appears in "Apps Using Your Apple ID" section of settins in iphone?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not done in Xcode.

You have to login to your [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com) account and then navigate to the "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" -> "Identifiers" -

Click on the Identifier you want to change:

[image: browser]

Then edit the "Description". Space chars are allowed, but many special chars are not.

[image: browser]

Finally, click the "Save" button on the top right.

Comment: How long to takes to show effect?